# jQuery live method on button not firing

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get data from these fields

```
<input type="text" id="distance1" placeholder="FROM"/>
<input type="text" id="distance2" placeholder="TO" />
<button id="distCalculate">Calculate!</button>
```

into jQuery to do something with them. But, this is not working:

```
jQuery(document).ready(fucntion(){
    jQuery('#distCalculate').live('click', function() { 
            alert('hi!');
            var d1 = $('#distance1').val();
            var d2 = $('#distance2').val();

            console.log('Vr: ' + d1 + d2);

            if(d1 != '' && d2 != '')
            {
                alert('vrednosti: ' +d1+' '+d2);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
     });
});
```

Not even initial alert() that says 'hi!' is not working. Anyone has clue?

Comment: what errors do you get ?

Comment: which jquery version are you using?

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(fucntion(){
 should be jQuery(document).ready(function(){

Comment: 1. I've changed spelling on function to correct
2. changed .live to .click

Still not working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you misspelled `function`.

Here's a more up-to-date version of your code (jQuery 1.7+), just as an example:

```
(function($) {
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#distCalculate', function() { 
                var d1 = $('#distance1').val();
                var d2 = $('#distance2').val();

                if (!isNaN(d1) && !isNaN(d2)) {
                    alert('vrednosti: ' + d1 + ' ' + d2);
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
         });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: The [docs](http://api.jquery.com/live/) say that *As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated.*

Comment: Okay thanks I need to review my code - but fortunately it is working still, just tested.

Comment: Yeah, it'll get removed sooner or later.

Answer (score 2):

> jQuery(document).ready(**fucntion**(){

should be

> jQuery(document).ready(**function**(){

Answer (score 0):

You have misspelled the keyword `function` in line 1 (fu **cn** tion)

Answer (score 0):

1. Correct 'function' spelling
2. Live() will not work for this kind of scenarios ,boss!

The reason is

Live() is a way of binding events to the elements that are dynamically being added in the course of user interactions.

The best suitable way of binding click event is 
a) use click() straightaway
2)bind('click',function())

Comment: live() is deprecated too! use on()

Answer (score 0):

Try this one....

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#distCalculate').live('click', function() { 
        alert('hi!');
        var d1 = $('#distance1').val();
        var d2 = $('#distance2').val();

        console.log('Vr: ' + d1 + d2);

        if(d1 != '' && d2 != '')
        {
            alert('vrednosti: ' +d1+' '+d2);
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
 });
});​
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jf4vP/) for that